# Billing form is not updating in magento 2

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation, billing

I am trying to updating the checkout forms telephone field validation. I have achieved this for shipping form but in billing form it is  not working.

For this I have done in my di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="phone_validation_in_billing_form" sortOrder="100"
        type="vendor\module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor"/>
</type>
```

And in my LayoutProcessor:

```
<?php
        namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

        use \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MagentoLayoutProcessor;


        class LayoutProcessor
        {

            public function afterProcess(MagentoLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
            {
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
            )) {

                foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                /* telephone */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone'])) {
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['telephone']['validation'] =  [
                                    'validate-number' => 1,
                                ];
                }


                }

                }
                return $jsLayout;
            }

            }
```

But nothing happened. My pluging is invoking because when I var_dump the variables it was showing but not doing anything.

Thanks

Comment: In variable $key I am getting "before-place-order" instead of payment method. I guess thats why its not working

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I just printed the $jsLayout and then guessed the telephone node manually from array. Here is what worked for me:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

use \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MagentoLayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessor {

    public function afterProcess(MagentoLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']["billing-address-form"]['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone']['validation'] = [
                    'validate-number' => 1,
                    "required-entry" => 1,
                    'min_text_length' => 8
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```